# Coloring the clouds with lasers

Tags: energy, visible-light, laser

What strength of laser would be needed to color or make projections of images upon clouds in the sky? I am assuming that this is possible, if not, please explain why.

For the purposes of this question, assume that there is some sort of building on the ground that is projecting lasers or some other sort of light into the clouds for decorative purposes. This means that the clouds cannot vaporize due to the energy, if possible.

I am aware that there are laws regarding use of lasers, especially regarding shooting of them into the sky, this is simply a theoretical question, not one that would actually be implemented in some way.

Comment: It will depends on the amount of ambient light. If you have ever been outside in the wilderness on a cloudness, moonless night, you will have see thousands of stars that you never saw before. In such an environment a conventional laser pointer can make a visible dot at a considerable distance. Once you can see one dot, you can extrapolate the calculation - for example 5 mW per dot times the number of dots you want to see. A few vectorized characters projected will take a lot less power than a full color movie...

Comment: Dave Lynch (artist) and Mike Nix (physicist) have actually done this! Check out "Project Nimbus" https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg22730310-600-rider-in-the-sky-stars-in-first-cloud-movie/